How to send MessagingStyle notification with FCM from admin SDK?
My current approach is send the data only message to device, Then show the notification in onBackgroundMessage callback via flutter_local_notifications plugin with MessagingStyle
fcm json
{
    token: token,
    data: {
      foo: 'bar',
    },
    android: {
      priority: 'high',
    },
  },
)

Android
 MessagingStyleInformation messagingStyleInformation =
      MessagingStyleInformation(
          conversationTitle: name,
          Person(name: name),
          messages: messages);

 AndroidNotificationDetails notificationAndroidSpecifics =
     AndroidNotificationDetails(channelId, channelName,
         styleInformation: messagingStyleInformation,
         channelDescription: channelDescription,
         groupKey: groupKey,
         tag: id);

 NotificationDetails notificationDetails =
     NotificationDetails(android: notificationAndroidSpecifics);

 await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin!.show(
     id,
     name,
     "last message",
     notificationDetails);

Since the data only message is low priority, So I might get throttled by device, Although  I didn't get throttled so far, But still looking for a approach to show MessagingStyle notification properly.
Maybe I can do something like:
{
    token: token,
    android: {
       notification: {
          stlye: "MessagingStyle"
       }
    },
  },
)


did you figure out how to do this?

No, we still need to handle it on client.
